# C - Server broadcasts IP for client

Tags: c

I need my server to broadcast a message (not that it matters but it contains its IP/port info). What I have currently is the working server broadcast, code below. I'm not sure about setting up the client because usually I would use the IP/port of the server which the client doesn't have until it receives the broadcast. The client never receives anything. Can someone tell me what is wrong.

Server:

```
struct sockaddr_in server, bcast;
int sockfd;
int blen = sizeof(bcast);
int svrlen = sizeof(server);
char buf[BUFLEN];
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1){
    printf("Socket error.\n"); 
    exit(1);
}

int broadcastPermission = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (void *)&broadcastPermission,sizeof(broadcastPermission)) < 0){
        printf("Error setting socket options.");
}

memset(&bcast, 0, sizeof(bcast)); 
bcast.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcast.sin_port = htons(PORT);
bcast.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

string bcastIP = BCASTIP;
if(inet_aton("255.255.255.255", &bcast.sin_addr) == 0){
    printf("Broadcast Address error.");
    exit(1);
}

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1){
    printf("Port error.\n");
    exit(1);
}

fflush(stdout);
if(int bytes = sendto(sockfd, ipinfo, sizeof(ipinfo), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&bcast, blen) == -1){
    printf("Broadcast send error.");
}
else{
    printf("Sent"):
}
```

Client:

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
int sockfd;
int bytes;
int svrlen = sizeof(server);
char buf[BUFLEN]
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1){
        printf("Socket error.\n"); 
        exit(1);
}

memset((char *)&server, 0, sizeof(server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(BPORT);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

while(1){
    printf("Waiting for broadcast...\n\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    memset(buf,0,BUFLEN);
    bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, (socklen_t*)&svrlen);
    printf("Received");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is not calling bind() on the socket before trying to receive data.

http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/BroadcastReceiver.c shows the following example which you may find helpful:

```
void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);  /* External error handling function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                         /* Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr; /* Broadcast Address */
    unsigned short broadcastPort;     /* Port */
    char recvString[MAXRECVSTRING+1]; /* Buffer for received string */
    int recvStringLen;                /* Length of received string */

    if (argc != 2)    /* Test for correct number of arguments */
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <Broadcast Port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    broadcastPort = atoi(argv[1]);   /* First arg: broadcast port */

    /* Create a best-effort datagram socket using UDP */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        DieWithError("socket() failed");

    /* Construct bind structure */
    memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof(broadcastAddr));   /* Zero out structure */
    broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet address family */
    broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  /* Any incoming interface */
    broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(broadcastPort);      /* Broadcast port */

    /* Bind to the broadcast port */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &broadcastAddr, sizeof(broadcastAddr)) < 0)
        DieWithError("bind() failed");

    /* Receive a single datagram from the server */
    if ((recvStringLen = recvfrom(sock, recvString, MAXRECVSTRING, 0, NULL, 0)) < 0)
        DieWithError("recvfrom() failed");

    recvString[recvStringLen] = '\0';
    printf("Received: %s\n", recvString);    /* Print the received string */

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a bind() call, but if I must, I must.

Answer (score 0):

> I need my server to broadcast a message (not that it matters but it contains its IP/port info).

That sounds a lot like service discovery. You should really use the standard mDNS/Zeroconf protocol for that. You can use the Avahi library for that (or use the Avahi service on Linux or Zeroconf on MacOS X).